# Attempting to make it so that if a year value is between 2 values you are assigned a certain title

Tags: javascript, html

The goal here is to make it so that when I put a value inside of the textbox, it will assign you a title based on what years you are between. However, it isn't working and JSFiddle is giving me the following error:

```
 "<a class='gotoLine' href='#48:26'>48:26</a> Uncaught SyntaxError:
 Unexpected token '&lt;='"
```

To my knowledge, this shouldn't even be an error. The symbol for less than or equal to is `<=` so I am unsure what the problem is.

```js
function ShowGeneration() {
  var yearBorn;
  var generation;
  var Boomer
  var X
  var Millenial
  var Z
  yearBorn = parseFloat(document.getElementById('yearBox').value);

  // insert if statements here to map yearBorn onto generation
  if (yearBorn >= 1944 && yearBorn <= 1964)
    generation = Boomer;
  else {
    if (yearBorn >= 1965 && yearBorn <= 1979)
      generation = X;
    else {
      if (yearBorn >= 1980 && yearBorn <= 1994)
        generation = Millenial;
      else {
        if (yearBorn >= 1995 && yearBorn <= 2015)
          generation = Z;
      }
    }
  }



  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = "You belong to the " + generation + " generation.";
}
```

```html
<p>
  What year were you born? <input type="text" id="yearBox" size="6">
</p>
<input type="button" value="Click for Generation" onclick="ShowGeneration();">

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Compound `if` conditions must have each test be a complete test. `yearBorn >= 1944` is a complete test, `<= 1964` is not. Should be: `yearBorn >= 1944 && yearBorn <= 1964`

Comment: Ok so I changed it and I changed it up above as well but now it is giving me the same error

Comment: Well it is still giving the same error even after I changed it

Comment: Ok so I think I have fixed everything, there are no error codes or anything but it is continuously returning a value of "you are part of the undefined generation"

Answer (score 1):

Fixed some of the syntax and formatting, see below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Generations</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function showGeneration() {

                var generation;

                var yearBorn = parseFloat(document.getElementById('yearBox').value);

                // insert if statements here to map yearBorn onto generation
                if (yearBorn >= 1944 && yearBorn <= 1964) {
                  generation = "Boomer";
                }
                else if (yearBorn >= 1965 && yearBorn <= 1979) {
                  generation = "X";
                }
                else if (yearBorn >= 1980 && yearBorn <= 1994) {
                  generation = "Millenial";
                }
                else if (yearBorn >= 1995 && yearBorn <= 2015) {
                  generation = "Z";
                }  

                document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = "You belong to the " + generation + " generation.";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p>
        What year were you born? <input type="text" id="yearBox" size="6">
      </p>
      <input type="button" value="Click for Generation"  onclick="showGeneration();">
      <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4horvmy/)

Mind you, anyone younger than `1944` or older than `2015` will still belong to the `undefined` generation; you should introduce these two cases in your `if` statements.

Comment: Gen Z unfortunately according to this code

Answer (score 0):

I found errors:

1. values of generation must be between quotations because they are strings
2. missing yearBorn in the comparison
3. missing curl brackets to close the if and function

try this

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Generations</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowGeneration() {
        var yearBorn;
        var generation;
        yearBorn = parseFloat(document.getElementById('yearBox').value);

        // insert if statements here to map yearBorn onto generation
        if (yearBorn >= 1944 && yearBorn <= 1964)
          generation = "Boomer";
        else {
          if (yearBorn >= 1995 && yearBorn <= 1979)
            generation = "X";
          else {
            if (yearBorn >= 1980 && yearBorn <= 1994)
              generation = "Millenial";
            else {
              if (yearBorn >= 1995 && yearBorn <= 2015)
                generation = "Z";

              document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = "You belong to the " + generation + " generation.";
            }
          }

        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>
      What year were you born? <input type="text" id="yearBox" size="6">
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="Click for Generation" onclick="ShowGeneration()">

    <div id="outputDiv"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That code doesn't have any of the fixes you mentioned? And I fixed everything the only issue like I said is it continuously says "you are part of the undefined generation"